# Android GoogleMap needs activation?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, offline

my current project is about an app and a GoogleMap that supports to be completely offline.

**Long story short:**

- I use a MapFragment with a *com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap*
- and also have an offline overlayDrawable and markers
- see http://codemax.de/upl/offline_map.png
- I don't really need the google maps itself, just the mapView

**Problem:**

My GoogleMap remains completely grey until it has at least ONCE an online connection. Once I got the connection my overlay+mapmarkers become visible. After this my map works totally fine offline.

**Question:**

How can I make my map (overlay+markers, nothing more...) work without ANY online connection? 
Furthermore: I didn't find any docs saying that there is a behaviour/activation like this...

.

*edit: I don't need any offline map material (I have an overlay!) and switching to another map api may unfortunately not be an option.*

Comment: the 250kb mapOverlay I want to display is totally enough ;) I just need the gmap to display that!

Comment: have you gone through OSM maps...they are working on same concept ...just check this link ..http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30

Comment: since I am using a huge framework with gmaps in it, it's not that easy to change the implementation from gmaps to another map, sry

Comment: do you showme how to implement the map, i develop apps whit google maps and work without any conection

Answer (score 3):

There is not much official information about this, but there are a couple of interesting threads on the *Google Maps API bug reports and feature requests* forum thread:

- [Issue 5017](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5017) (Status: Fixed) solves the problem of the map loading *every time the device goes offline*, but with the following note:

> (...) There is still a requirement for an internet connection when the application is first loaded but there is no longer an issue with later opening the application and using the map while there is no connection.

- [Issue 5496](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5496) (Status: **New**) was post on Jun 12, 2013 and is not solved yet:

> Currently, you need an internet connection on the first activity launch to even enable offline functionality on the Map fragment.
>   Is it possible to allow loading of tiles using an offline tile provider without doing the initial API key check esp. when the map type is GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE? I think the API key check should really be limited to cases where map type is anything besides MAP_TYPE_NONE.

So, based on the existing information (or lack of it), an Internet connection is required when the application is first loaded to check the API key. After that, the application will work completely offline.

Comment: even though this (unfortunately) doesn't solve my problem, it's still the best answer! Thanks a lot for your help - you deserved the bounty!

Comment: Glad to help! I'm very interested in this issue because I'm also developing an offline google maps application. If I find a solution, a workaround or some clue I will update my answer

Comment: Sounds great, I'd really appreciate that! Good luck on your research!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the GoogleMap Type to NONE?

```
myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMapType(int)
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#MAP_TYPE_NONE

I'm not sure but it's easy to try.
Anyway as far as I know you have to provide a valid api key in order to use GoogleMaps API, and it could be that a first connection is needed to validate that key...

Comment: Yep, I tried that. =/ As you can see in the screenshot there's a blank background, thanks to this maptype parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google map won't work without connection, it will need it at least for checking the application api key

Comment: that's my thought as well, but I did not find any official documentation or source proving that. furthermore there are some apps out there that don't have that problem - however.

Comment: Are you sure the apps that do not have the problem use the v2 maps api? AFAIR with v2 it was possible to use it completely offline - but not with the new one